# pygraphviz error: program neato not found in path

Tags: python, pygraphviz

I'm running `Windows 7`, and using python version 2.7.

I've been trying to use `pygraphviz`, but whenever I use `G.layout()` on a graph, I get the error message;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    G.layout()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1305, in layout
    data=self._run_prog(prog,' '.join([args,"-T",fmt]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1251, in _run_prog
    runprog=r'"%s"'%self._get_prog(prog)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py", line 1239, in _get_prog
    raise ValueError("Program %s not found in path."%prog)
ValueError: Program neato not found in path.
```

I know, however, that the `Graphviz` files are installed, and the directory is in my path (I've manually gone and added it).

I've tried the simlink solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679434/how-to-run-neato-from-pygraphviz-on-windows) but all I get when I enter that into the command line (administrator mode) is a message saying it is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file. I'm not experienced enough to know whether there's something I'm failing to do with that though.

Is there something I can do to make this work?

Comment: Is this command `neato -V` work in your cmd console?

Comment: Yes, that gives version number as expected.

Comment: @meta Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with conda. Apparently there is something wrong with the libraries. This comment in here worked for me:

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1851#issuecomment-314924385

In the Anaconda prompt do both:

```
conda install -c anaconda graphviz
```

and

```
conda install -c anaconda python-graphviz
```

Then `import graphviz` will work.

Comment: Please include the actual instructions to address this problem in your answer. It's appropriate to cite the source as you have, but you should also include the fix (in your own words) in case that link stops working.