# Improving Python NetworkX graph layout

Tags: python, networkx

I am having some problems in visualizing the graphs created with python-networkx, I want to able to reduce clutter and regulate the distance between the nodes (I have also tried spring_layout, it just lays out the nodes in an elliptical fashion). Please advise.
[image]

Parts of code:

```
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=predges, edge_color='red', arrows=True)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=black_edges, arrows=False, style='dashed')
# label fonts
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,font_size=7,font_family='sans-serif')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G,pos,q_list,label_pos=0.3)
```

Comment: I think it's best to export your graph to Gephi, which has lots of layout algorithms and other helpful visualization features.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

In networkx, it's worth checking out the graph drawing algorithms provided by [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) via [`nx.graphviz_layout`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout.html).

I've had good success with `neato` but the other possible inputs are

- `dot` - "hierarchical" or layered drawings of directed graphs. This is the default tool to use if edges have directionality.
- `neato` - "spring model'' layouts.  This is the default tool to use if the graph is not too large (about 100 nodes) and you don't know anything else about it. Neato attempts to minimize a global energy function, which is equivalent to statistical multi-dimensional scaling.
- `fdp` - "spring model'' layouts similar to those of neato, but does this by reducing forces rather than working with energy.
- `sfdp` - multiscale version of fdp for the layout of large graphs.
- `twopi` - radial layouts, after Graham Wills 97. Nodes are placed on concentric circles depending their distance from a given root node.
- `circo` - circular layout, after Six and Tollis 99, Kauffman and Wiese 02. This is suitable for certain diagrams of multiple cyclic structures, such as certain telecommunications networks.

In general, [graph drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing) is a hard problem. If these algorithms are not sufficient, you'll have to write your own or have networkx draw parts individually.

Comment: for problems with `graphviz_layout` refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279733/what-could-cause-networkx-pygraphviz-to-work-fine-alone-but-not-together

Comment: usage: `nx.draw(G, pos=graphviz_layout(G))`

Comment: Adding to @DiCaprio, first install pygraphviz: `pip install pygraphviz` then `nx.draw(G, pos=nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G))`

Comment: `pip install pygraphviz` on Windows gave error (something to do with wheels) but since I use `Anaconda`, `conda install -c anaconda graphviz` worked fine

Comment: regarding @curtisp's instructions, no need for anaconda, see the install instructions at: https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html#windows

Answer (score 20):

I found this to be useful for quickly visualizing interaction data (here, genes) sourced as a CSV file.

**Data file [a.csv]**

```sh
APC,TP73
BARD1,BRCA1
BARD1,ESR1
BARD1,KRAS2
BARD1,SLC22A18
BARD1,TP53
BRCA1,BRCA2
BRCA1,CHEK2
BRCA1,MLH1
BRCA1,PHB
BRCA2,CHEK2
BRCA2,TP53
CASP8,ESR1
CASP8,KRAS2
CASP8,PIK3CA
CASP8,SLC22A18
CDK2,CDKN1A
CHEK2,CDK2
ESR1,BRCA1
ESR1,KRAS2
ESR1,PPM1D
ESR1,SLC22A18
KRAS2,BRCA1
MLH1,CHEK2
MLH1,PMS2
PIK3CA,BRCA1
PIK3CA,ESR1
PIK3CA,RB1CC1
PIK3CA,SLC22A18
PMS2,TP53
PTEN,BRCA1
PTEN,MLH3
RAD51,BRCA1
RB1CC1,SLC22A18
SLC22A18,BRCA1
TP53,PTEN
```

**Python 3.7 venv**

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = nx.read_edgelist("a.csv", delimiter=",")

G.edges()
'''
  [('CDKN1A', 'CDK2'), ('MLH3', 'PTEN'), ('TP73', 'APC'), ('CHEK2', 'MLH1'),
    ('CHEK2', 'BRCA2'), ('CHEK2', 'CDK2'), ('CHEK2', 'BRCA1'), ('BRCA2', 'TP53'),
    ('BRCA2', 'BRCA1'), ('KRAS2', 'CASP8'), ('KRAS2', 'ESR1'), ('KRAS2', 'BRCA1'),
    ('KRAS2', 'BARD1'), ('PPM1D', 'ESR1'), ('BRCA1', 'PHB'), ('BRCA1', 'ESR1'),
    ('BRCA1', 'PIK3CA'), ('BRCA1', 'PTEN'), ('BRCA1', 'MLH1'), ('BRCA1', 'SLC22A18'),
    ('BRCA1', 'BARD1'), ('BRCA1', 'RAD51'), ('CASP8', 'ESR1'), ('CASP8', 'SLC22A18'),
    ('CASP8', 'PIK3CA'), ('TP53', 'PMS2'), ('TP53', 'PTEN'), ('TP53', 'BARD1'),
    ('PMS2', 'MLH1'), ('PIK3CA', 'SLC22A18'), ('PIK3CA', 'ESR1'), ('PIK3CA', 'RB1CC1'),
    ('SLC22A18', 'ESR1'), ('SLC22A18', 'RB1CC1'), ('SLC22A18', 'BARD1'), 
    ('BARD1', 'ESR1')]
'''
G.number_of_edges()
# 36

G.nodes()
'''
  ['CDKN1A', 'MLH3', 'TP73', 'CHEK2', 'BRCA2', 'KRAS2', 'CDK2', 'PPM1D', 'BRCA1',
    'CASP8', 'TP53', 'PMS2', 'RAD51', 'PIK3CA', 'MLH1', 'SLC22A18', 'BARD1',
    'PHB', 'APC', 'ESR1', 'RB1CC1', 'PTEN']
'''
G.number_of_nodes()
# 22
```

---

**UPDATE**

This used to work (2018-03), but now (2019-12) gives a `pygraphviz` import error:

```py
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout

nx.draw(G, pos = graphviz_layout(G), node_size=1200, node_color='lightblue', \
    linewidths=0.25, font_size=10, font_weight='bold', with_labels=True)

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    ImportError: libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file:
      No such file or directory
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    ImportError: ('requires pygraphviz ', 'http://pygraphviz.github.io/')
```

**SOLUTION**

Outside Python (at the venv terminal prompt: `$`) install `pydot`.

```sh
pip install pydot
```

Back in Python run the following code.

```py
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.read_edgelist("a.csv", delimiter=",")
# For a DiGraph() [directed edges; not shown]:
#   G = nx.read_edgelist("a.csv", delimiter=",", create_using=nx.DiGraph)

nx.draw(G, pos = nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G), node_size=1200, \
    node_color='lightblue', linewidths=0.25, font_size=10, \
    font_weight='bold', with_labels=True)

plt.show()    ## plot1.png attached
```

The main change was to replace

```py
nx.draw(G, pos = graphviz_layout(G), ...)
```

with

```py
nx.draw(G, pos = nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G), ...)
```

**References**

[Remove matplotlib depreciation warning from showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57436705/remove-matplotlib-depreciation-warning-from-showing)

[What could cause NetworkX & PyGraphViz to work fine alone but not together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279733/what-could-cause-networkx-pygraphviz-to-work-fine-alone-but-not-together)

- Specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40750101/1904943

---

**Improved plot layout**

It is difficult to decrease congestion in these static networkx / matplotlib plots; one workaround is to increase the figure size, per this StackOverflow Q/A: [High Resolution Image of a Graph using NetworkX and Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255964/high-resolution-image-of-a-graph-using-networkx-and-matplotlib) :

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(20,14))
# <matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x7f1b65ea5e80>

nx.draw(G, pos = nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G), \
    node_size=1200, node_color='lightblue', linewidths=0.25, \
    font_size=10, font_weight='bold', with_labels=True, dpi=1000)

plt.show()    ## plot2.png attached
```

To reset the output figure size to the system default:

```py
plt.figure()
# <matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x7f1b454f1588>
```

---

**Bonus: shortest path**

```py
nx.dijkstra_path(G, 'CDKN1A', 'MLH3')
# ['CDKN1A', 'CDK2', 'CHEK2', 'BRCA1', 'PTEN', 'MLH3']
```

---

**plot1.png**
[image: plot1.png]

**plot2.png**
[image: plot2.png]

---

Although I did not do this here, if you want to add node borders and thicken the node border lines (node edge thickness: `linewidths`), do the following.

```py
nx.draw(G, pos = nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G), \
    node_size=1200, node_color='lightblue', linewidths=2.0, \
    font_size=10, font_weight='bold', with_labels=True)
# Get current axis:
ax = plt.gca()
ax.collections[0].set_edgecolor('r')
# r : red (can also use #FF0000) | b : black (can also use #000000) | ...
plt.show()
```

Comment: You, mam, are a hero.  In particular, the documentation of options in `.draw` in this answer exceed the like documentation in the actual `networkx` docs, IMO.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel : the joy in your comment outweighs any upvote I'll ever receive on this answer!  ;-)

Comment: When I later returned to this code (~21 mo later), I was getting a `pygraphviz` import error. `pip install pygraphviz` seemed to go smoothly, but I could not `import pygraphviz` (same error; ditto when on my Arch Linux system I installed `python-pygraphviz` via `yay -S python-pygraphviz`.  I updated my answer, above, with the solution.

Comment: Also, in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59473049/1904943) I load TSV data into a Pandas dataframe, then color the nodes according to the data columns in the Pandas dataframe.

Comment: Hi, great answer! However, when running the first part `nx.draw(G, pos nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G), ...)` I am getting this error: `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] "neato" not found in path.` Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Comment: @Bendemann : you're using Windows?  I'm not sure; h/e on my (Arch Linux) system while NetworkX is available as a package, I don't have it installed through my operating system, but  rather via `pip` in Python (`pip list | grep networkx; pip show networkx`).  Check the comments in these posts? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679434/how-to-run-neato-from-pygraphviz-on-windows | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672123/filenotfounderror-winerror-2-neato-not-found-in-path

Comment: @Bendemann ... Also, see accepted answer, above -- perhaps explicitly specifying a `prog` other than `neato` may work? "prog (string (default: ‘neato’)) – The name of the GraphViz program to use for layout. Options depend on GraphViz version but may include: ‘dot’, ‘twopi’, ‘fdp’, ‘sfdp’, ‘circo’" | https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout.html

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. In my case the problem was with outdated packages. An overall update of `conda` solved the problem. I have one more doubt, how could I specify the variable `scale` in order to increase the global distance between the nodes given your solution? I cannot specify it like this for e.g. `pos = nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G,  scale = 10)`

Comment: @Bendemann : NetworkX lacks utility for the display of large graphs, imo.  Alternatives that allow more flexibility include [Cytoscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytoscape)  (see also my [blog post](https://persagen.com/2019/08/20/kegg_pathways_cytoscape.html)) -- which looks intimidating at first use, but allow facile import of tabular data as source, relation, target as well as a plethora of display options / configuration, plugins, ...

Answer (score 5):

You have a lot of data in your graph, so it is going to be hard to remove clutter.

I suggest you to use any standard layout. You said that you used `spring_layout`. I suggest you to try it again but this time using the `weight` attribute when adding the edges.

For example:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph();
G.add_node('A')
G.add_node('B')
G.add_node('C')
G.add_node('D')
G.add_edge('A','B',weight=1)
G.add_edge('C','B',weight=1)
G.add_edge('B','D',weight=30)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G,scale=2)

nx.draw(G,pos,font_size=8)
plt.show()
```

Additionally you can use the parameter `scale` to increase the global distance between the nodes.

Comment: And how does the weights affect the algorithm? Higher weight == nodes get closer or the other way around?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question how to regulate the distance between nodes, I expand on [Hooked's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21990980/65889):

If you draw the graph via the Graphviz backend and when you then use the `fdp` algorithm, you can adjust the distance between nodes by the [*edge* attribute `len`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:len).

Here a code example, how to draw a graph `G` and save in the Graphviz file `gvfile` with wider distance between nodes (default distance for `fdp` is `0.3`):

```
A = nx.to_agraph(G)
A.edge_attr.update(len=3)
A.write(gv_file_name)
```

Two comments:

1. It is normally advisable to adjust `len` with the number of nodes in the graph.
2. The `len` attribute is only recognised by the `fdp` and `neato` algorithm, but not e.g. by the `sfdp` algorithm.

Comment: Please provide more information: AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'to_agraph'

Comment: @user3352632 At the moment I am not using NetworkX. The method names in the networkx package might have changed since 2015. Please check NetworkX' doco.

Answer (score 0):

So, this may not be useful for original question, but maybe for future searchers :

A solution can be

```py
    pos = nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G)
    nx.draw(G, pos=pos)
```

Think of installing `agraph` first with `pip install agraph`.
(The solution with `nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G)` is now to be depreciated according to networkx.)

Hope it helps :)