# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] "neato" not found in path

Tags: networkx, graphviz

I am trying to visualize my network. While there is no error in installing and importing the pydotplus and networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout, when I try to draw it, I am receiving the error below.

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] "neato" not found in path.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you install Graphviz on your machine?

Comment: Yes I've also installed Graphviz and Pygraphviz

Comment: Sometimes `pydot` works bad for me. Try to use `agraph` in `networkx`, maybe it will help you.

Comment: I tried it and its giving me an error of ImportError: ('requires pygraphviz ', 'http://pygraphviz.github.io/') so I tried installing it again, and it gives me an PackagesNotFoundError for some reason

Comment: Something is wrong with your packages... Sorry, I can't help you, I mostly use Graphviz on Linux.

Comment: Ok thanks. Just a last question. Do you happen to know a remedy for this error AssertionError: 1 "neato" with args ['-Tdot', ] returned code: 1

Comment: `dot` is another program from Graphviz. `-T` is the output format of a graph, like `-Tpng`, `-Tsvg` or `-Tdot` (returns DOT file). Looks like you have an incorrect graph that can't be parsed with `neato`.

Comment: But I was able to display the graph using the normal spring_layout

Comment: Because spring_layout doesn't use `Graphviz`, it is the part of `networkx`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without additional libraries, look at this answer, which shows a way to get a hierarchical tree layout or a circular layout purely in networkx:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29597209/2966723